# Copy HYPERLINK function to include link as well as friendly name

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following in cell A1 of my worksheet:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.stackoverflow.com","Great website")
```

In cell B1, I have:

```
=A1
```

Unfortunately in B1 it displays just the `Great website` part of the function in A1 but it isn't hyperlinked.

How can I copy both the link and the cell contents so that the displayed contents in B1 are correctly linked?

Comment: I have submitted an answer, it works in office 365. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text "http://www.stackoverflow.com" in cell E1

Change A1 of your worksheet

```
=HYPERLINK(E1,"Great website")
```

and B1 to be the similar formula as A1.

```
=HYPERLINK(E1,A1)
```

I know this is cheat, but it will work!

I think this is a good technique as it makes the maintenance of the URL: easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for Sheet1, please try:

```
Sub LinkCopy()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
End Sub
```

Comment: The very latest. I use Office 365 so I'm always up to date. Must be something I've not enabled perhaps? It's a macro enabled worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
Sub CopyValuesAndNumberFormats()
   Dim CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range
   Set CopyRng = Application.Selection
   Set CopyRng = Application.InputBox("Ranges to be copied :", xTitleId, CopyRng.Address, Type:=8)
   Set PasteRng = Application.InputBox("Paste to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
   CopyRng.Copy
   PasteRng.Parent.Activate
   PasteRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```